# He wants to open his own business, but needs a push in the right direction to get him started

Tags: grammar, parsing, noun-phrases

> He wants to open his own business, but needs a push **in the right direction** to get him started.

Source: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/push_2

Does "**in the right direction**" form a noun phrase with "a push"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition  phrase *in the right direction* is complement of the head *push*.

The phrase *a push in the right direction* is considered by some as a noun phrase but by others as a determiner phrase.

The "DP analysis or the DP hypothesis" considers such a phrase a determiner phrase, headed by *a*.  "Others reject this analysis in favour of the more traditional NP (noun phrase or nominal phrase) analysis" where *push* would be the head of the phrase, and *a* is merely a dependent

[Determiner phrase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase)